# Problemas na exibição de acentos PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, query, collation

Estou tentando exibir a palavra **Chapéu** no meu site mas aparece **Chap�u**

Meu HTML está com:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

No MySQL a db inteira está com collation **utf8_swedish_ci** e todos os acentos, ç são exibidos corretamente dentro da database, mas quando passo para o PHP através da query me retorna com � (somente dados pegos da DB)

Em outro tópico vi esta opção: **utf8_decode()** mas ela em vez de retornar **�** me retorna **?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido setando UTF-8 no PHP depois de iniciar a conexão com MySQL

```
$connection->set_charset("utf8")
```